# Access Denied trying to change io_scene_fbx/__init__.py

Tags: python, scripting

is there any specific developer environment for scripts in blender?

I wanna change `__init__.py` inside

```
Blender Foundation\Blender\2.76\scripts\addons\io_scene_fbx\
```

and I get access denied from windows

I wanna change

```
"version": (3, 6, 5),
```

to `"version": (3, 7, 5),`

but I would apply more changes

any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are [several places](https://www.blender.org/manual/getting_started/installing_blender/directorylayout.html#ms-windows) blender looks for python scripts/addons:

> ## MS-Windows
>
> #### LOCAL
>
> ```
> .\2.76\.
> ```
>
> #### USER
>
> ```
> C:\Documents and Settings\$USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.76\
> ```
>
> #### SYSTEM
>
> ```
> C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.76\
> ```

Generally the *system* path isn't writable for a standard user, but naturally this depends on the platform and your specific configuration. Try copying the script to the *user* path (you may get warnings about duplicate addons).

The *local* path applies to versions of blender installed though an archive extracted anywhere on your system, as opposed to an installer or package. (e.g. for a local install on windows, [the .zip download](https://www.blender.org/download/) can be used)